# Calculator in one string with priority

Tags: java, regex, string, optimization, calculator

How can I create a better solution without stacks or otherwise optimize this code.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Calc
{

    // (15+25)+((15+25)+5)


    public static String calc(String a, String b, String operator){


            switch (operator) {

                    case "+": return Double.valueOf(a) + Double.valueOf(b)+"";

                    case "~": return Double.valueOf(a) - Double.valueOf(b)+"";

                    case "*": return Double.valueOf(a) * Double.valueOf(b)+"";

                    case "/": return Double.valueOf(a) / Double.valueOf(b)+"";

                }

            return null;

        }


    //difference with operator '-'..i replace this operator to ~

    public static String minustotild(String s){

            String result = ""+s.charAt(0);

            for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++){

                    if ((s.charAt(i) == '-') && ("+-*(/~".indexOf(s.charAt(i-1)) == -1))   // if previous char is not a symbol( is digit)

                        result += ""+'~';

                    else result +=""+s.charAt(i);

                }

            return result;

        }

    public static String operate(String expression){


            String num[];   int index = -1;  
            Character priorityOperator='/';  // default
            String operators;
            while (!((  operators = expression.replaceAll("[^*+/~]","")  ).isEmpty()))     // while have operator..
                {   

                    if ( (index = operators.indexOf('/')) == -1){        // choose priority operator
                        priorityOperator = '*';
                        if  ( (index = operators.indexOf('*')) == -1){
                                priorityOperator=operators.charAt(0);
                                index = operators.indexOf(priorityOperator);
                            }
                    }
                    num = expression.split("[^0-9\\-.]"); // сплитим все числа..

                    // заменяем строкое представление арифметики,на строковой результат с помощью калк(). 
                    expression=expression.replaceFirst(num[index]+"\\"+priorityOperator+num[index+1], calc(num[index],num[index+1],""+priorityOperator)); 

                }

            return expression;

        }


    public static String operateBracket(StringBuilder s, int startIndex){
            // ''
            // 3+4+(4+(3+3)+5)+(4+)
            if (startIndex == -1) {        // если скобок нету то оперируем .
                    return (operate(s.toString()));
                }
            else {   
                    int k = 1;
                    for (int i=startIndex+1; i < s.length(); i++){

                        if (s.charAt(i) == '(')  
                                k++;
                            else if ((s.charAt(i) == ')')) 
                                {
                                    if (k == 1) {    // нашли конец первой скобки. не знаю как лучше сделать)

                                            String newBracket = s.substring(startIndex+1, i);

                                            s=s.replace(startIndex,i+1,operateBracket(new StringBuilder(newBracket), newBracket.indexOf(""+'(')));

                                        }
                                    k--;
                                }

                        }
                }

            return operate(s.toString());

        }





    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner s = new Scanner( System.in );
        String b = s.next();

             do  {

                   StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder(minustotild(b));
                   System.out.println(" result = "+operateBracket(a,a.indexOf(""+'(')));

              }   while ( (b = s.next()) != "null");


        }

}
```

Comment: You seem to imply this code is working essentially but just want an optimised version?  Because there is no problem in the code this post is arguably off-topic for SO

Comment: yes :) also without java language dependency..however i think about general solution,not scripts or another library ,and etc :)

Comment: returning null, unless for specific reasons, is typically a bad idea. Return empty String instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @BartKiers This isn't a perfect fit for Code Review, though it might be okay.  But whether or not something is on-topic on Code Review should not impact whether or not you vote to close here on Stack Overflow.  The only reason to vote to close a question here on Stack Overflow is because it is off-topic on Stack Overflow.  Questions that are on-topic on other Stack Exchange sites are not inherently off-topic here.

Comment: @BartKiers, I agree with nhgrif. In accordance with SO guidelines, it is perfectly OK to ask about coding techniques, which this question falls under.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can create an Operation interface:

```
public interface Operation
{
    double apply(double x, double y);
}
```

Then, you create your concrete operations:

```
public enum BasicOperation implements Operation
{
    PLUS("+") {
        public double apply(double x, double y) { return x + y; }
    },
    MINUS("-") {
        public double apply(double x, double y) { return x - y; }
    },
    TIMES("*") {
        public double apply(double x, double y) { return x * y; }
    },
    DIVIDE("/") {
        public double apply(double x, double y) { return x / y; }
    };

    private final String symbol;
    BasicOperation(String symbol)
    {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return symbol;
    }
}
```

And then you create your logic to use these operations:

```
public class ExtensibleEnumOperationTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number (i.e. 1.43): ");
        double x = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter another number: ");
        double y = input.nextDouble();
        input.close();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Testing Basic Operations using Bounded Type Token (Item 29)");
        test(BasicOperation.class, x, y);

        System.out.println("Testing Basic Operations using Bounded Wildcard Type (Item 28)");
        test(Arrays.asList(BasicOperation.values()), x, y);

        System.out.println("Testing a single operation:");
        Operation op = BasicOperation.PLUS;
        System.out.println(x + " + " + y + " = " + op.apply(x, y));     
    }

    private static <T extends Enum<T> & Operation> void test(Class<T> opSet,
        double x, double y)
    {
        for (Operation op : opSet.getEnumConstants())
            System.out.printf("%f %s %f = %f%n", x, op, y, op.apply(x, y));
        System.out.println();
    }

    private static void test(Collection<? extends Operation> opSet, double x,
            double y)
    {
        for (Operation op : opSet)
            System.out.printf("%f %s %f = %f%n", x, op, y, op.apply(x, y));
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

This should work well. In addition, it will allow you to expand your operations by creating another `enum` that implements `Operation`. For instance, exponent or remainder.  This code was taken from the book ***Effective Java*** **Item 39**

Comment: thanks i test it :) but minimum language speciality need. in other words, algorytm solution . with standart capabilities

Comment: @aquavita_x what part is non-standard? Enumerations have been part of Java since Java 5. This isn't about algorithms. If anything, using the character '~' for subtraction is non-standard. IF you want a simpler solution, take the enum and place it inside your test class (with main method). The problem is that the solution will not be extendable.